# udev rules driving me nuts

Tags: udev, serial-port, usb-device

I have this `usb-serial` device:

```
root@imx6_armboard:/etc/udev/rules.d# udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{latency_timer}=="1"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-1.1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface}=="FT232R USB UART"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1':
    KERNELS=="2-1.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}==" 90mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="30409"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0600"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="9"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{product}=="FT232R USB UART"
    ATTRS{serial}=="A400CZBK"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb2/2-1':
    KERNELS=="2-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  2mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="15513"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="2513"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0bb3"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="3"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb2':
    KERNELS=="usb2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  0mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="48"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0300"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.0.35-02671-gb0836db ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{product}=="Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{serial}=="fsl-ehci.1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1':
    KERNELS=="fsl-ehci.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="fsl-ehci"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS=="
```

I tried to create a rule for this in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbserial-sensors.rules`. this one

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb-serial", KERNEL=="ttyUSB?", ATTRS{serial}=="A400CZBK", SYMLINK+="sensO2"
```

I spent a **WHOLE** day, looking into documentation and running `udevd` and `udevadm` in debug mode trying to figure out why did this rule not work as expected.

In the end (of the day), this rule worked:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB?", ATTRS{serial}=="A400CZBK", SYMLINK+="sensO2"
```

so basically, i used the clause SUBSYSTEM***S***=="**usb**"  instead of SUBSYSTEM="usb-serial".

and the question is WHY did it work? Why doesn't `usb-serial` trigger the `udev` daemon. Especially when it is there exactly so that one can grab it with `udevadm info`???

Thank you

Comment: Is it spelled `SUBSYSTEM` in the rule you were using before or is that just a typo you made when you wrote this question? The key not being valid (since it's `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"` in your `udevadm` output above) would probably cause the rule to not match.

Comment: @Bratchley `SUBSYSTEM` is valid. It differs from `SUBSYSTEMS` in that it does not check parent nodes in the device tree. See `man 7 udev`.

Comment: Did `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"` work? Note those (`usb-serial` and serial number) are on different levels of the tree.

Comment: @derobert I am almost certain among the things I tried was `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial" too. but I can't be certain now. I shall try this tomorrow and get back to you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a udev rule, you can only match against one device. You can choose which device to match against, but you can't mix conditions from multiple devices. As it says in the output of `udevadm info`:

> A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
>   and the attributes from **one single parent device**.

The one parent that has `ATTRS{serial}=="A400CZBK"` has `KERNELS=="2-1.1"` and `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`. The target device itself has `KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"` and `SUBSYSTEM=="tty"`. So you can use any of these. But you can't use `SUBSYSTEM=="usb-serial"`, which is not present on any device, nor `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"`, which is only present on a different parent.

Comment: why is `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"` not usable? Could I not have used `KERNELS=="ttyUSB0" , SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"` , which are both from the same parent device of the target ?

Comment: @nass You can have both `KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"` and `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"` but you can't have `ATTRS{serial}=="A400CZBK"` because it's in a different parent.

Comment: hm, it is still not clear. I can use `KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", SUBSYSTEM=="tty"`. so this must be because it IS the device itself. but why is the parent of that device not usable? Should I assume that the device is at the deepest level and only there? Because if the deepest lvl is the device, then why is 1 lvl up not usable but the ATTRS which is 3 lvls up is usable?

Comment: @nass It's not a matter of how deep it is. You can use attributes from ONE parent only, in addition to the device itself. You can choose any parent, but all the attributes must be from the one parent that you choose, or from the device itself.